# Linear search prints both found and not found for value present in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Statement getting executed after loop and printing.

For `linearsearch` code I have tried few possibilities but I'm not sure why the last print statement gets executed?

```
def linearsearch(list, n):
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if(list[i] == n):
            return True
list = [4, 6, 8]
n = 4
if search(list, n):
    print("Found")
print("Not found")
```

Expected output:

> Found

Actual result:

> Found
>
> Not found

Answer (score 2):

`print("Not found")` is simply the last line item in the code you have posted, so it will always be executed. You have not included any condition to prevent that line from executing. As an aside, you are not calling your `linearsearch()` function at all.

You probably meant to do something like the following instead (referenced your `linearsearch()` function and renamed your `list` variable as `items` because it is not a good idea to stomp on built-ins):

```
items = [4,6,8]
n = 4
if linearsearch(items, n):
    print("Found")
else:
    print("Not found")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this makes sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be more Pythonic and simpler if `linearsearch()` were written this way:

```
def linearsearch(list, n):
    return n in list
```

Here is the output of an example usage:

```
>>> def linearsearch(list, n):
...     return n in list
... 
>>> linearsearch([1,2,3], 1)
True
>>> linearsearch([1,2,3], 4)
False
>>>
```